# How can I merge arrays in the .blade page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two arrays named `$ticket` and `$answers` which are passed to the view. Here is my code in the blade:

```
@foreach($answers as $answer)
    <div class="description">{{$answer->desc}}</div>
    <div class="author">{{$answer->user->name}}</div>
@endforeach
<div class="description">{{$ticket->desc}}</div>
<div class="author">{{$ticket->user->name}}</div>

{{$answer->render()}}
```

My code works good when there isn't any pagination. But when `{{$answer->render()}}` prints, then the ticket will be appeared in all pages. That's not what I want. I want to print it only in the last page. In other word, I want to merge `$ticket` with `$answers` as the last item of that (`$answers` are sorted descending).

How can I do that?

Comment: If there is any relation bw answer and ticket then use relation or use join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$loop->last` to add last value as ticket

```
 @if (count($answers))
 @foreach($answers as $answer)
     <div class="description">{{$answer->desc}}</div>
     <div class="author">{{$answer->user->name}}</div>
    @if ($loop->last)
       <div class="description">{{$ticket->desc}}</div>
       <div class="author">{{$ticket->user->name}}</div>
    @endif
 @endforeach
 @else
       <div class="description">{{$ticket->desc}}</div>
       <div class="author">{{$ticket->user->name}}</div>
 @endif
```

Comment: In this case, the ticket will not be printed when it doesn't have any answer.

Comment: @Shafizadeh : It's easy to print with `!count($answers)` then. Please comment on this now